# How to change ClickOnce IdentityVersion using MSBuild.exe?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, clickonce, azure-pipelines

Good time,

I use Visual Studio Build step in the TFS build, with MSBuild Arguments

```
/target:MyProject:publish /property:ApplicationVersion=VersionNumber
```

After the deploy of new version application already installed doesn't want to update. I checked manifest file, and revealed that VersionNumber applied to the version of entryPoint element, instead of version of assemblyIdentity element.

Is that fixable in the build step, or I should change manifest by my own script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of assemblyIdentity is according to the target application, so you need to change AssemblyVersion in AssemblyInfo.cs file of target application. (can’t do it through MSBuild)

There are many extensions that contain related step/task to do it, such as: [Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task), [Update AssemblyInfo](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastianlux.UpdateAssemblyInfo). (Update the version before build)

Comment: thanks a lot. 
I've changed ApplicationVersion and Revision in the .csproj file instead of AssemblyInfo, but I suppose it provides the same result.